# Make a login/logout that changes name depending on the status

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have tried to set up `login_status` variable at first and then getting the button to change every time the button press definition is called. Below is what I'm stuck with I can get it to work when it is on its own but as soon as I as a class it fails

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import StringVar

program_name="Quick Testing"
global loginout_button
loginoutbutton = StringVar()


def loginout_press():
    if loginout_button['text'] == "Log In":
       loginout_button.configure(text="Log Out")

else:
    loginout_button.configure(text="Log In") ###

class ProgramMain (tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title(program_name)
        user_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg="grey", bd=2, relief="raised")
        user_frame.place(relx=0, rely=0.0, relwidth=9, relheight=1)
        loginout_button = tk.Button(user_frame, text="Log In", fg='black', bg="grey", font='bold 10',
                                command=loginout_press)
        loginout_button.place(relx=0.0, rely=0.0, relwidth=0.12, relheight=1)


app = ProgramMain()
app.mainloop()
```

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'

Comment: Welcome @idlovetocode. It is nice to have new members to the site, but I gotta tell you, the question was poorly written. The community is way more likely to help you if you demonstrate willingness to put in the effort. Please, consider being more careful in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Marc

It wasn't a lack of effort more I knew what what i wanted just wasn't sure how to explain it. I will look through how other people put their questions together so I do a better job in the future. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: That's great to know. I also advise revising the question after you first write it, and before you click Post, to make sure the text is clear. Thank you for your commitment, and once again, welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You should make your function `loginout_press` a method of the class `ProgramMain` instead. Also right now your `loginout_button` is a local variable rather than a class attribute.

Here is how to wrap everything inside your `ProgramMain` class:

```
import tkinter as tk

program_name="Quick Testing"

class ProgramMain (tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title(program_name)
        user_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg="grey", bd=2, relief="raised")
        user_frame.place(relx=0, rely=0.0, relwidth=9, relheight=1)
        self.loginout_button = tk.Button(user_frame, text="Log In", fg='black', bg="grey", font='bold 10',
                                command=self.loginout_press)
        self.loginout_button.place(relx=0.0, rely=0.0, relwidth=0.12, relheight=1)

    def loginout_press(self):
        if self.loginout_button['text'] == "Log In":
            self.loginout_button.configure(text="Log Out")
        else:
            self.loginout_button.configure(text="Log In")

app = ProgramMain()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: HI Henry I had tried to do that before but failed to put self between the parentheses and self. when calling the button. Anyway thanks for your help.